# Jmeter distributed testing 2 slave systems

Tags: jmeter, system, slave

I am running a jmeter test with one master and two slave systems.
the values I provided in master system are:

```
no of threads: 750
ramp up: 420 seconds
loop count: 1
```

when I press `ctrl+shift+R`, the test execution begins on both "A" & "B" remote systems and the message

> "Starting the test on host XXX.XXX.X.XXX @ Mon Feb 8 08:08:21 IST 2016
>   "

is displayed on cmd prompt of both systems.

But after sometime I found that there is no response from server. I checked if there is any activity in the "summary listener", but there is no activity.
I checked the generated "summary.xlsx" file and found all the requests from system "A" have been served and only some of the requests from system "B" were served.

When I checked system A's cmd prompt it says

> "Finished the test on host XXX.XXX.X.XXX @ Mon Feb 8 08:08:21 IST 2016
>   ".

(I think it is ok, because all its requests were served).

When I checked system B's cmd prompt I **DIDN'T** find the message

> "Finished the test on host XXX.XXX.X.XXX @ Mon Feb 8 08:08:21 IST 2016
>   ".

Hoping that the requests of system B would be executed eventually, I left it for 8 hours.

But to my surprise when I checked it in the morning it was just, where I have last seen it.

No further requests from system B were executed, checked the server log no response there either. And I also **didn't** find the message

> "Finished the test on host XXX.XXX.X.XXX @ Mon Feb 8 08:08:21 IST 2016
>   "

on system B.

Please suggest me how I can get all the requests from both slave systems served without the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can bet that the issue is in different subnets. Read [the following](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) step by step manual, especially limitations section:

> RMI cannot communicate across subnets without a proxy; therefore neither can jmeter without a proxy.

So, make sure that both A and B are in the same subnet with master.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are able to run a standalone/non-distributed test in Slave B w/o issues. If you have not checked that, please ensure if it works fine.

In this case, read this site. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-port-forwarding-set-up-load-testing-on-compute-engine/. It has good information on the jmeter communication during distributed testing.

I would check if the RMI ports on slave B are open.